# Fortran 95: Array function return. Out-of-bounds

Tags: arrays, fortran, indexoutofboundsexception, fortran95

I have a simple problem in a rather simple code, but I  really dont get to find the error after some hours. Here a minimised version of the code, where the problem occurs:

```
SUBROUTINE Partial_KlassRKV(x,y,f,f_xMarge,f_yMarge)
    USE DGL_Functions
    IMPLICIT NONE

    REAL :: x(:),y(:),f(:,:,:),f_xMarge(:,:),f_yMarge(:,:)
    INTEGER :: i,j,k
    REAL :: partial_fx(6,6)

    DO k=1,size(f,3)

       partial_fx=PartialCalc(x,y,f(:,:,k),f_xMarge,f_yMarge)
       WRITE(*,*) 'Nach PartialCalc x'
       STOP

    END DO  

...

MODULE DGL_Functions
CONTAINS

FUNCTION PartialCalc(x,y,f,f_xMarge,f_yMarge) 
    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL :: x(:),y(:),f(:,:),f_xMarge(:,:),f_yMarge(:,:)
    REAL :: PartialCalc(6,6)
    INTEGER :: i,j


    DO i=1,size(PartialCalc,1)
        DO j=1,size(PartialCalc,2)
            PartialCalc(i,j)=i+j
        END DO  
    END DO 

    WRITE(*,*) 'PartialCalc ',PartialCalc


END FUNCTION PartialCalc
```

It returns the last WRITE-statement in FUNCION PartialCalc but not the WRITE after

```
partial_fx=PartialCalc(x,y,f(:,:,k),f_xMarge,f_yMarge)
```

in the SUBROUTINE. At that line there is "Array subscript out of bounds". I dont understand this. Both arrays (partial_fx and PartialCalc) are declared with dim (6,6) and a value is assigned to each PartialCalc(i,j)...?

Greets intasys

PS:I am using Plato f95 with Checkmate 32.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try a different compiler.   gfortran and ifort normally identify the array and even the index value that is the problem.   Here is a example that I quickly wrote:

```
module mysubs

contains

subroutine subxy (x,y)
   real, dimension (5) :: x, y
   x = 4.0
   y = 5.0
end subroutine subxy

end module mysubs

program test_bounds
   use mysubs
   real :: x(4), y(5)

   call subxy (x, y)

   write (*, *) x, y

end program test_bounds
```

gfortran, with the right compiler options, finds this at compile time, with useful specificity:

```
   call subxy (x, y)
               1
Warning: Actual argument contains too few elements for dummy argument 'x' (4/5) at (1)
```

Comment: Thank you. Changing debugger to win 32 debug solved the problem. Just in case anyone has a similar problem.